# Rails Generate New Image on Direct Visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

Wasn't sure the best way to word this, but basically I want to have an image with a direct link like this:

mysite.com/whatever/image.png

The image is a countdown to a certain event (done as an image so it can be embedded into more restrictive systems). The time to the event is pulled from a MySQL database then an image is generated with Imagemagick.

Can I get rails to perform the call that generates the image on the visit of that URL, so the PNG is always up to date? Or am I better off setting up a scheduled task to generate a new PNG with the same name every x minutes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will have no problem serving a custom image (remember, on the web, content type is determined by the Content-Type header, not the filename, although generally it's easiest to keep the two in sync); however, since generating an image via ImageMagick can take up a lot of server resources, you'll probably want to either cache the image or -- as you suggest -- generate it periodically.

To serve an image from your controller, see the [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) documentation.